# How to reload synonyms.txt in Solr?

Tags: lucene, solr, indexing, synonym

When I changed my synonyms.txt I only see the diferences when I do this:

- restart solr server
- indexed some item (empty commit?)

Some knows a way to reload synonyms.txt file without restart server?

Tks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Reloading the core](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD) should also reload synonyms. I almost always map indexes to cores (even if it's only one core per instance) due to the enhanced flexibility it provides (as in this case).